# std::chrono doesn't work if passing a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I came across a weird error with std::chrono,
If I do something like this:

```
TimeHandling time(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000 / 125));
time.start();
```

Everything is ok.
But if instead I put the milliseconds value in a variable:

```
int mpl = 1000 / 125;
TimeHandling time(std::chrono::milliseconds(mpl));
time.start();
```

g++ throw this error:

```
 request for member ‘start’ in ‘time’, which is of non-class type ‘TimeHandling(std::chrono::milliseconds) {aka TimeHandling(std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >)}’
```

Does someone know why ?

Comment: Seems like most vexing parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second version declares a function with a parameter called `mpl`

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/most-vexing-parse/info

C++11 allows you to use braces to disambiguate initializations from declarations:

```
TimeHandling time{std::chrono::milliseconds(mpl)};
```

or, using braces for both initializations:

```
TimeHandling time{std::chrono::milliseconds{mpl}};
```

Comment: Lots of ways to disambiguate in fact. `static_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(mpl)` or `std::chrono::milliseconds(1 * mpl)` will also work.

Comment: I used the syntax TimeHandling time((std::chrono::milliseconds(mpl)))
Which I find less disturbing.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
TimeHandling time(std::chrono::milliseconds(mpl));
```

declares a function that returns a `TimeHandling` object, and take an `std::chrono::milliseconds` parameter named `mpl`.

When a compiler faces the dilemma of considering this kind of statement either as a function declaration or as a constructor call, it's forced (by the standard) to consider it as a function declaration.

Use brace initialization to correct this problem and disambiguate the statement.